# Same ssh key to different repositories

Tags: git, mercurial, ssh-keys

Is it possible to access `git` and `hg` repos with the same ssh public key?

The problem is: I can access to my git repo but when I try to access my hg repo it asks me for `hg` user password instead of ssh key password.

The error is in my public config or in mercurial server config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't add your public key to whatever is hosting your hg repo and cares about authentication.

Comment: I've added my public key, but it keeps asking me for hg user credentials. I'm assuming that the problem is in my side, because other users can access to server correctly.

Comment: @Bjorn is right. This has nothing to do with using a key for different repositories. You can do that as much as you want. This is simply a matter of your not adding your key properly, or not having appropriate permissions, or something like that.

Comment: I will assume that @Bjorn is right and will contact my system administrator. Thank you